# complexity of time constructible function

Tags: computational-complexity

In field of computational complexity there is a definition of **time constructible function**.

As example, in any reasonable and general model, functions like $t_1(n) = n^2, t_2(n) = 2^n$, and $t_3(n) = 2^{2^n}$ are computable in $poly(\log t_i (n))$ steps.

I would to know why it's exactly $poly(\log t_i (n))$ steps?

How can I show it?